# Can we retract the use of `rel=nofollow` for links that reference the MDN documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

In an effort to increase the awareness of the quality of the [Mozilla JavaScript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), I would really enjoy if W3Schools was knocked off their place in Google for many top searches. Mozilla's documentation is top notch and they do deserve to have Google place weight on the links that are upon answers.

Comment: I don't know enough about SEO to tell whether it would have a measurable impact, but either way it sounds like a pretty cool idea.

Comment: It would for sure knock out W3schools.

Comment: It might - or not, depending on how Google weighs links from a single site, and whether they will outweigh the rest of the web that foolishly links to W3Schools. But I totally agree it's worth a try.

Comment: Given this "[Remove `nofollow` on links deemed reputable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable)" I'm surprised that they're not already un-`nofollowed`-ed...

Comment: Can we also implement the opposite and *always* append `rel="nofollow"` to W3Schools links no matter what?

Comment: While I surely appreciate (and support) the idea: for a single site to make that difference, I'm afraid Google would need to adjust their algorithms a bit. (Either to allow a single site to have such an impact, or to *not* make some automatic filters/penalties kick in when this is detected.) But then why wouldn't they make the same tweaks without SO changing anything? Surely there are people at Google who feel the same (though Mozilla is also somehow a competitor).

Comment: Well providing links to MDN would improve their ranking. These things happen all the time.

Comment: I think the question is, should Stack Exchange be officially endorsing the MDN as a quality resource? I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: Who is the authority in JavaScript reference then?

Comment: I'd almost prefer to see a per-site-configurable (editable by mods and high-rep users, or something like that) list of sites that never get nofollow, or at least where the threshold for nofollow removal is something super-low.

Comment: @BillyMailman: Yes, I'd expect the same for MSDN links. They may be competing with themselves rather than other useless sites, but I hate to see the WinCE 6.0 version of an API at the top of the search results when the Win7 version is what I really want.

Comment: @Gabe: it would also be interesting to see if we can give preference to the MSDN links which do not include the version numbers, though I expect that would require community editing first.

Comment: Just like my comment about a single site not being able to have such impact is just a wild guess, am I right to assume that your *"It would for sure knock out W3schools"* is also just a feeling? If not, any reference for that?

Comment: Maybe similar to community ads, there could be a special meta question for "nofollow-free" links where you can propose URL schemas to be exempted, and people can vote on the exemptions, and if there are enough upvotes, the corresponding links will be exempted (maybe there should also be a minimum number of upvotes on the question/answer the link appears in for the "nofollow" to be removed).

Comment: @OneKitten it doesn't have to be a matter of [se] officially endorsing [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). [main] is ***user-generated*** content. The users can endorse it `:P`

Comment: Nope, @Cupcake, it's the Stack Exchange team that would need to make the changes to remove the nofollow. (As you can see in the generated HTML of those dummy links in your comment.)

Comment: @Arjan that's not quite what I meant. By the very fact that we're discussing this right here right now, ***users*** are driving the decision on whether or not to endorse MDN.

Comment: [You wish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-declined%5D+votes%3A100), @Cupcake ;-)

Comment: Google should correct their algorithm. It is a crime that W3Schools has the top spot.

Comment: I don't think this is StackOverflow's job.  It's Google's job.  The only fair thing SO could do is to remove `nofollow` from all links, and let the users vote with their answers.  I agree MDN is the best right now, but will it always be?

Comment: Although I *love* MDN, I think http://www.webplatform.org/ would be a better site to "endorse" as it is for the entire web platform, and backed by all major players (including Mozilla).

Comment: W3Schools is at the top because it is good for beginners. MDN is too much information when answering a question by a beginner.

Comment: W3Schools and MDN have different target audiences. It seems W3Schools are targeting beginner audiences while MDN targets those advanced audience who prefer the full reference. Also in the real spirit of Internet, StackOverflow shouldn't be biased to handling things links. There maybe other ranking mechanisms you may want to consider. Maybe bookmarks are weighed also. Just maybe.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take your word for it that MDN is a great source of documentation on the JavaScript implementation *in Mozilla browsers*.

But JavaScript and ECMAScript are standards, not controlled by development teams of individual browsers.  And browser-specific extensions are not standard, no matter how much market share that browser has.

For that reason, I disagree with your desire to help implementation-specific documentation command the top spot on a Google search.  I wouldn't want MSDN getting top search result for C++11 topics either.  And I'm sure you'd be very unhappy if SO pushed MSDN to the top of JavaScript searches.

Naturally for information on the Mozilla XUL language, or Mozilla plugin model, MDN ought to command the top spot.  Just as for Win32 APIs, MSDN should because it is the canonical reference for those.

That doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea for Stack Exchange to be in the business of promoting those developer sites and helping them get PageRank.

So I say, keep `nofollow` on links to documentation that isn't vendor-neutral.  And yes @animuson, `nofollow` on all w3schools links, because quality IS important.

Comment: MDN isn't really implementation-specific. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions

Comment: @bjb568: MSDN tries to cover the standard also, by including "Microsoft Specific" heading for extensions or deviations.  But invariably, examples, recommendations, and everything else are based off what works best in a single implementation.  But feel free to disagree.  You won't hurt my feelings downvoting an answer on meta. And I don't use enough Javascript to know whether there exists any neutral documentation of sufficient quality, or if the only reasonable choices are which vendor's docs to use.

Comment: Fine, it may work best on FireFox, but it's still the best documentation for all browsers.

Comment: @BenVoigt, have you used MDN? I use it as my primary ECMAScript reference. In fact, it is pretty accurate on cross browser support. I challenge someone to find a better ECMAScript reference for Chrome or Safari, than MDN. (MSDN is pretty good for IE.)

Comment: MDN is a wiki, and pretty vendor-neutral when it comes to the basics. (It also offers documentation on building Firefox extensions, for example, but quite separately.)

Comment: I agree. StackOverflow should put `rel=nofollow` on all outbound links that do not go to the StackExchange network.

Comment: MDN also offers documentation for Chrome-specific features, e.g. the virtual FileSystem API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System.

Comment: @Romoku That will have negative SEO implications for SO.

Comment: @JohnConde: Yeah, it’s working out really badly so far ;)

Comment: @JohnConde I'm not that familiar with SEO. What kind of implications would it have and are they really that big of a concern? StackOverflow answers are usually on the first page of Google search results.

Comment: I rmemeber a few years ago with SO having issues with scraper sites ranking higher than them in Google. They worked directly with Google to correct the issue. One of the changes they made was to link out to some authoritative sites as that is a ranking factor (one of many but one nonetheless). Apparently Google felt it was important for SO to make that change.

Comment: @Romoku, do you really want `rel=nofollow` on [*all* outbound links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22*%22)? Then [Remove nofollow on links deemed reputable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable) should be reverted.